# I am developing an Android app using Kivy and I wanted to know that how can I add MDCard in Scrollview? Currently I am using kivyMD and Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, scrollview, kivymd

Whenever I try this code I get error and also if I keep only MDCard then also its appears but not in Scrollview.
This is my code:

```
ScrollView:

    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True

    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width
        padding: 10, 10
        text:
            'My text\n' * 100
    MDCard:
        Label:"Hello"
```

Comment: Attach a minimal example code that people can run and look at the error you are describing here. Also attach the text of the error itself.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ScrollView documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#scrolling-behavior):

> The ScrollView accepts only one child

That may be the cause of your error. Try something like this in your `kv` file:

```
ScrollView:

    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding: 10, 10
            text:
                'My text\n' * 100
        MDCard:
            Label:
                text: "Hello"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
```